# Node version manager issue on mac

Tags: node.js, nvm

I am installing nvm on mac using the command

> curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/install.sh | bash

After installed I am opening new tab. But I keep getting error `zsh: command not found: nvm`. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the issue was I was using bash before and now have zsh which was only inserting the env loading lines in `.bashrc`. I had to copy the following lines manually into `.zshrc`.

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

Check and add these lines if they are not in it already.

This has been mentioned in the [wiki](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#troubleshooting-on-macos) as well.

Comment: This was the issue!

Answer (score 1):

My issue was exactly what deepakchethan has mentioned. I just removed the bash_profile file and reinstalled. Nvm with same command and it worked properly this time.